# Parse JSON in SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I'm looking to parse a single return in JSON into multiple rows.

The string is this -

```
{"policy_ids":["INZP2981-11000002","INZP-00001786","0AAAA01PC06"]}
```

I want to just parse this so that it is a row for each policy_ids. I've tried using OpenJSON WITH however I keep returning NULL values.

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) ;

SET @json = N'{"policy_ids":["INZP2981-11000002","INZP-00001786","0AAAA01PC06"]}' ;

SELECT
    *
FROM
    OPENJSON(@json) 
    WITH (   
              policy_ids   varchar(200) '$.policy_ids' 
 )
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: JSON functions are specific to databases, so you really need a database tag.  You would need one anyway, but the question cannot be answered "in general".

Comment: @GordonLinoff as A god of mysql :) would "you" recommend storing JSON into  mysql db at all?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Sorry have tagged accordingly.

Comment: @B001ᛦ . . . I store JSON in some of the tables that I'm responsible for.  It is just another data type and has its uses.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you very much for your response. I was just concerned because of the missing normalization in that case and have not dared yet to store JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a different statement to parse the `$.policy_ids` JSON array. You may try tou use `OPENJSON()` with default schema (without the `WITH` clause). In this case the result is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type` and the `value` column returns the value of each item in the input array.

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) ;
SET @json = N'{"policy_ids":["INZP2981-11000002","INZP-00001786","0AAAA01PC06"]}' ;

SELECT [value] AS policy_id
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.policy_ids')
```

Result:

```
policy_id
-----------------
INZP2981-11000002
INZP-00001786
0AAAA01PC06
```

If you want to use an explicit schema, the statement is:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.policy_ids') WITH (   
   policy_id varchar(200) '$'
)
```